# Carousel in dialog disappears, Vue and Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I put the carousel in the dialog, which triggered by clicking the image. But, after a minute (no matter you keep clicking on and off), the pictures in carousel will disappear. No errors in the F12 console. Stuck with hours for no clues.

No errors in F12 console neither.

`enter code here`https://codepen.io/Joey-Deakin/pen/MLpGQQ

Comment: Fixed!!! Looks like carousel is active all the time even without dialog get called. So I make it only active when dialog is active.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was driving me crazy, because nothing seemed to be broken. Thank you so much for coming up with the answer!